# Find element by XPath in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I would like to extract some odds from the website:

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/champions-league-2015-2016/real-madrid-manchester-city-dhJZn1pn/#1X2;2

For example, the home odds for 1xbet is 1.5, and I copy the XPath expression for this odds and insert it into *find_element_by_Xpath*.

Here is my little code:

```
> from selenium import webdriver from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>
> driver = webdriver.Firefox() url =
> 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/champions-league-2015-2016/real-madrid-manchester-city-dhJZn1pn/#1X2;2'
> driver.get(url) print(driver.title)
>
> element =
> driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/a[2]")
>
> print(element.text)
>
> driver.close()
```

Unfortunately the answer is an error:

> hao@hao-ThinkPad-T420:~$ ./testodds.py  Real Madrid - Manchester City
> Betting Odds, Soccer - Champions League 2015/2016 Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "./testodds.py", line 12, in 
> element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/a[2]")
> File
> "/home/hao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
> return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "/home/hao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 978, in find_element
> 'value': value})['value']   File "/home/hao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/home/hao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
> locate element:
> /html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/a[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath expression is not correct.

Your XPath expression is this:
`"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/a[2]"`

You want this:
`/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[8]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div`

Here is the full working code. I successfully scraped the odds with it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url ='https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/champions-league-2015-2016/real-madrid-manchester-city-dhJZn1pn/#1X2;2'
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[8]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div")
print(element.text)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Another question :

Comment: When I use the inspector to copy the xpath on the odd 1.5 It gives me :

Comment: /html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/  the miskate come from div[7] why ?

Comment: @ahmedaao I am not quite sure which element that is, but they often throw in fake elements to deter scrapers like you. Companies are generally not happy that people do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this XPath expression:

```
.//table[@class='table-main detail-odds sortable']/tbody/tr/td[2]/div
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath expression.

> //div[@id="odds-data-table"]//td//a[contains(text(), "1xBet")]//ancestor::tr//td[2]

It's better to write your own XPath expression rather than copying from the browser as the browser gives a very tightly constructed XPath expression based on the element position relative to the nearest element with id or from your root. If any change occurs at any place, your XPath expression will not work.